# IntelliJ,Cucumber, TestNG: Did any one try running a single scenario from the feature file?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, testng

I have IntelliJ 2017.1 with TestNG and Cucumber. I can run the test from the testng.xml. However, when I try the same to run from the Cucumber feature file in IntelliJ by right mouse on the scenario and click Run, none of the settings in the testng.xml are honored. There is no way to specify testng.xml for Cucumber in Edit Configurations. Is there a workaround for this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To run a scenario

1. In the Project tool window, right-click the desired feature file, or open it in the editor.
2. On the context menu of the desired scenario, point to Run, and then choose Run Scenario .

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does not honor the testng.xml settings. There are capabilities like driver.capabilities.model and other settings like env.resources in the xml that need to be used for the test run from the feature file context menu. There should be some Run Configuration I am supposed to do for this to work. Do you have that Configuration info?